# How can I use realm database to store strings for recyclerView?

Tags: android, database, database-connection, realm, android-database

Currently I am using array of strings to store 'title' and 'content' for textviews inside cardView but realm database sounds to be a better idea for this purpose. How can I accomplish this? Here is my recycler adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
    private ClipData myClip;
    private Context context;

    public List<CardItemModel> cardItems;

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<CardItemModel> cardItems){
        this.cardItems = cardItems;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView copyButton;
        ImageView shareButton;
        ToggleButton favButton;

        TextView title;
        TextView content;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            this.content = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_content);
            this.copyButton= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.copyButton);
            this.shareButton=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

            this.favButton=(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favButton);

            favButton.setChecked(false);
            favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));


        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(cardItems.get(position).title);
        holder.content.setText(cardItems.get(position).content);
        holder.copyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){


                myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


                myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", holder.content.getText().toString());
                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Copied to clipboard" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            }
        });
        holder.shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("text/plain");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, holder.content.getText().toString());
                v.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Text"));
            }
        });

        holder.favButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton favButton, boolean isChecked){
                if (isChecked)
                    favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

                else
                    favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(), R.mipmap.ic_cart));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardItems.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<CardItemModel, RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
    private ClipData myClip;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<CardItemModel> cardItems){
        super(cardItems, true); // this is `realm.where(CardItemModel.class).findAllSortedAsync("someField");
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView copyButton;
        ImageView shareButton;
        ToggleButton favButton;

        TextView title;
        TextView content;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
            this.content = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_content);
            this.copyButton= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.copyButton);
            this.shareButton=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);

            this.favButton=(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.favButton);

            favButton.setChecked(false);
            favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));


        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CardItemModel cardItem = getData().get(position);
        holder.title.setText(cardItem.title);
        holder.content.setText(cardItem.content);
        holder.copyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", holder.content.getText().toString());
                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Copied to clipboard" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();    
            }
        });
        holder.shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("text/plain");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, holder.content.getText().toString());
                v.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Text"));
            }
        });

        holder.favButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton favButton, boolean isChecked){
                if (isChecked)  favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

                else favButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(favButton.getContext(), R.mipmap.ic_cart));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And `CardItemModel` will `extends RealmObject`. The adapter will show whatever is in Realm.